# Hijacking behavior data-filter with data-add-back-btn JQM 1.4.5 /jQM 1.3.2?

Tags: html, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm throwing in the towel and posting to stackoverflow. I've been working on this problem for hours every day. Nothing works for me. I'm in the midst of JQM HADES or something of my own ignorance/making. Probably the latter.

Problem: I have a jqm/cordova app that I'm trying to update. Using JQM 1.4.5, Jquery-2.2.3. (also tried in several different iterations of JQM & J. ie.1.0, 1.3.2, with the same results.

I have 2 pages. Page 1(JQM List with search bar) --->links to Page 2(Details of the list)

I am using a list view on Page 1 that displays a json file that is read into the list dynamically with spry.js. I also have a list view search bar. The search bar is where I'm having trouble.

```
 <div data-role="page" id="page1">     
      <div data-role="header" data-back-btn="true">
              <h1>text</h1>
                <a href="#page1" data-role="button" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-right">home</a>
       </div>

    <div>
    <ul data-role="listview" id="listing">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li></ul>
    </div>

   <div data-role="content" spry:region="ds1" ">    
       <ul data-role="listview" id="myList"  
         data-filter="true"
         data-filter-placeholder= "Select a sign below or search signs here..." 
          data-divider-theme="a">


                <li spry:repeat="ds1" spry:setrow="ds1" data-theme="a" id="myList">
                     <a href="#{page}"> 
                     <p class="ui-li-aside">{desc1}</p> 
                     <br>
                     <img src={imageurl} class="imglistViewStyle">
                  <span class="no-ellipses">{name}</span></a>
                 </li>
            </ul>       
        </div>
      </div>
```

After selecting an item on Page 1, Page 2 shows the details about a selected item. I then go back to the listing page1 by selecting a back button, an href header button, or a navbar button with href.

THEN, if I click the search icon on the search bar (page 1), the page is hijacked back to the previous item description page.

*I've tried coding href to the page

```
<a href="#page1" data-role="button" data-icon="carat-r" data-iconpos="notext" class="ui-btn-left">home</a>
```

and removing the data-back-btn code. The same thing always happens. I've used data-back-btw code data-rel that doesn't work. Nothing seems to take away the hijacking behavior. I can't find a way to clear everything between page transitions. I've tried JQM pagebefore and some other transitions to no avail. I've tried using a navbar instead of the data-back-buttons in the header. Even that doesn't work. I'm not good at describing this.

Page 2

```
<!--Page 2-->
<div data-role="page" id="page2" class="repeaterBackground">

       <div data-role="header" data-add-back-btn="true" >
          <h1>text </h1>

   </div>

    <div data-role="content"> 
    <span spry:detailregion="ds1">
  </span><span spry:detailregion="ds1">
        <p class="aside">{levelLongDesc}</p> 
        <p>
          </p>
          <a href="#{page}" style="text-decoration:none; color:black;"><span >&nbsp;{name}</span></a>
        <p class="centerButton">
        <img src={imageurl} width="80%" height="auto" class="detailSignFrame";></p>
    <p class="justify">{description}</p>
      </span>
    </div>

</div>
```

Obviously, I'm no expert. Sheesh! It took me 2 hours to get this posted and styled successfully. Please be kind. I am trying. TIA-Rachel

Comment: `pagecontainerhide`.

Comment: Spent last night and this morning trying to figure out what you meant by 'pagecontainerhide'. Google, stack overflow, JQM docs,jsfiddle. Tried many code iterations. Old and new versions. Best was pagehide. That gave me a blank page, but at least something happened. :-D

Please, would someone show or direct me to a specific example of how to use this with html and css? This isn't making sense to me. JQM used to be reasonably understandable. Now, it seems --harder for "regular" people. -Rachel

Comment: True, unfortunately after introducing `pageContainer` things have changed. The event I mentioned in my previous comment, also triggers when you navigate from page to another. If page 2 has an ID `$(document).on("pagecontainerhide", function(e, ui) { if ( ui.fromPage.id == "yourID") { $(".ui-content", ui.fromPage).empty(); } });`

Comment: Still not working. If I want to clear out page 2 when going back to page1, I would write:    `...(ui.fromPage.id=="page2")`  ??? When I do this, I can still click on the search bar icon and get the hijack back to the previous page2. <sigh> Thank you for trying to help me. Obviously, I don't know much js.

Comment: You want to clear content in page2 when you navigate back to page1? Maybe `ui.prevPage` I forgot. 'console.log(ui)` and check what you get. I remember ui.toPage, ui.prevPage, maybe I made  fromPage up.

Comment: OK Omar. Thank you for all of your good help. I will keep investigating the various statements and see what works for me. -Rachel